# How do I allow for multiple possible responses in a discord.py command?

Tags: python-3.6, discord.py

I'm attempting to set up a Discord bot while being relatively new to discord.py (and in reality, Python 3). I want to add the command "greet", which will prompt the user to say "hello" to it. It only responds to "hello", however, when I want it to respond to both "hello" and "Hello".

The only things I could think about fixing it was placing them in an `or` statement, which in theory should've made Python 3 and the bot choose between the two responses (as shown below).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('~greet'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Say hello')
        msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content=('hello' or 'Hello'))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello.')
```

The original code I had for it was simple and only allowed for the one response of `hello`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('~greet'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Say hello')
        msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content=('hello' or 'Hello'))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello.')
```

For some reason I can't wrap my head around, it's still not recognizing `'Hello'`, and only ever allowing me to say `'hello'` in response.

Comment: Is this the rewrite or async branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`or` doesn't behave how you think it does.  `'hello' or 'Hello'` is evaluated before being passed to `wait_for_message`, and is equal to `'hello'`.

Instead, you can provide a `check` function to `wait_for_message`:

```
def is_hello(message):
    return message.content.lower() == 'hello'

msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, check=is_hello)
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer definitely most directly solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `command` notation instead of checking for each message using `on_message` because it will make your code more readable. What will happen if you have 10 commands? Will you check for 10 strings in your `on_message`?

If thats's rewrite branch then the `commands.Bot` accepts a case_insensitive parameter:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
```

Alternatively, if you want to use multiple words for the same command you can use aliases for example:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['info', 'stats', 'status'])
    async def about(self):
        # your code here
```