# How do i put more than one command leading to the same response in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "fase":
        channel = (mychannel)
        await message.channel.send("Fase 1")
```

I'm trying to make the message.content detect multiple words and send the same message.channel.send
I tried

```
if message.content.lower() == "fase", "estagio", "missao", "sala":
if message.content.lower() == ("fase", "estagio", "missao", "sala"):
if message.content.lower() == "fase" or  "estagio" or "missao" or "sala":
if message.content.lower() == ("fase" or  "estagio" or "missao" or "sala"):
```

I read this post: [How do I allow for multiple possible responses in a discord.py command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553158/how-do-i-allow-for-multiple-possible-responses-in-a-discord-py-command)

That is the same exact problem but in his case it was the CaseSensitiveProblem that i already fixed in my code

And the second code for multiple words was:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
@bot.command(aliases=['info', 'stats', 'status'])
    async def about(self):
        # your code here
```

And i did it and got a lot of errors that made the bot not even run (im using PyCharm with discord.py 1.4.1 and python 3.6):

```
#import and token things up here
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='i.')
@bot.command(aliases=['fase', 'estagio', 'missao', 'sala']) #'@' or 'def' expected
    async def flame(self): #Unexpected indent // Unresolved reference 'self'
        if message.content(self): #Unresolved reference 'message'
            await message.send("Fase 1") #Unresolved reference 'message' // Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT
```

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: `if message.content.lower() in ("fase", "estagio", "missao", "sala")`

Comment: i forgot "in" existed, thank you helped me a lot with this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to use the [`Commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=command) extension:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
@bot.command(aliases=['info', 'stats', 'status'])
async def about(ctx):
    #Your code here
```

Every commands have the following in common:

- They are created using the `bot.command()` decorator.
- By default, the command name is the function name.
- The decorator and the function definition must have the same indentation level.
- `ctx` (the fist argument) will be a [`discord.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) object, which contains a lot of informations (message author, channel, and content, discord server, the command used, the aliase the command was invoked with, ...)

Then, `ctx` allows you to use some shortcuts:

- `message.channel.send()` becomes `ctx.send()`
- `message.author` becomes `ctx.author`
- `message.channel` becomes `ctx.channel`

Command arguments are also easier to use:

```py
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

#Command call example: !hello @Mr_Spaar
#Discord.py will transform the mention to a discord.Member object
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx, member: Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} says hello to {member.mention}')

#Command call example: !announce A new version of my bot is available!
#"content" will contain everything after !announce (as a single string)
@bot.command()
async def announce(ctx, *, content):
    await ctx.send(f'Announce from {ctx.author.mention}: \n{content}')

#Command call example: !sum 1 2 3 4 5 6
#"numbers" will contain everything after !sum (as a list of strings)
@bot.command()
async def sum(ctx, *numbers):
    numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
    await ctx.send(f'Result: {sum(numbers)}')
```